# nginx reformat request_uri to access real file path

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I want serve static files with nginx.

User will request like this format:

```
http://test.com/files/ea624cf923ea
```

Actual file location will like this

```
/files/ea/62/4c/f923ea
```

How can I serve this file?

I'm stuck with this:

How to split `request_uri` and send reformatted `request_uri` or some variable to `try_files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
location /files/ {
    rewrite "^(/files/..)(..)(..)(.{6})$" $1/$2/$3/$4 break;
}
```